# Characteristic not shown - does iOS have specifications for BLE peripheral characteristics

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, characteristics, bluetooth-peripheral

I have a custom Bluetooth peripheral with a service and one characteristic, which takes a value. On Android it works well, but with an iPhone it is just possible to connect, but the characteristic is not shown in any of the Bluetooth tool apps i used (nRF, LightBlue...)

We use a custom UUID, is this a problem for Apple?

EDIT: Here is the code

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "bsp.h"
#include "mg_api.h"


#include "mg126_ble_item.h"



/// Characteristic Properties Bit
#define ATT_CHAR_PROP_RD                            0x02
#define ATT_CHAR_PROP_W_NORSP                       0x04
#define ATT_CHAR_PROP_W                             0x08
#define ATT_CHAR_PROP_NTF                           0x10
#define ATT_CHAR_PROP_IND                           0x20
#define GATT_PRIMARY_SERVICE_UUID                   0x2800

#define TYPE_PRESENTATION_FORMAT  0x2904
#define TYPE_CHAR                 0x2803
#define TYPE_CFG                  0x2902
#define TYPE_INFO                 0x2901
#define TYPE_xRpRef               0x2907
#define TYPE_RpRef                0x2908
#define TYPE_INC                  0x2802
#define UUID16_FORMAT             0xff


// ===== Device Information Service =====
#define SOFTWARE_INFO "v1.6"
#define MANU_INFO     "FREXIT"
// ======================================

// ===== GAP =====
char DeviceInfo[9] =  "Spionglas";  /*max len is 24 bytes*/
// ===============

// ===== Item Service =====
char itemCharacteristicUserDescription[18] = "Show item solution";
byte cccd[2] = { 0, 0 };
// Format:1, Exponent:1, Unit:2, NameSpace:1, Description:2
byte itemCharacteristicPresentationFormat[7] = {0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x27};


uint16_t cur_notifyhandle = 0x21;


uint8_t* getDeviceInfoData(uint8_t* len)
{
  *len = sizeof(DeviceInfo);
  return (uint8_t*)DeviceInfo;
}


void updateDeviceInfoData(uint8_t* name, uint8_t len)
{
  memcpy(DeviceInfo, name, len);
  ble_set_name(name, len);
}


/**********************************************************************************
                 *****DataBase****

  01 - 06  GAP (Primary service) 0x1800
  03:04  name
  07 - 0f  Device Info (Primary service) 0x180a
  0a:0b  firmware version
  0e:0f  software version
  10 - 19  LED service (Primary service) 6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E
  11:12  6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E(0x04)  RxNotify
  13     cfg
  14:15  6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E(0x0C)  Tx
  16     cfg
  17:18  6E400004-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E(0x0A)  BaudRate
  19     0x2901  info
************************************************************************************/


typedef struct ble_character16 {
  uint16_t type16;          //type2
  uint16_t handle_rec;      //handle
  uint8_t  characterInfo[5];//property1 - handle2 - uuid2
  uint8_t  uuid128_idx;     //0xff means uuid16,other is idx of uuid128
} BLE_CHAR;

typedef struct ble_UUID128 {
  uint8_t  uuid128[16];//uuid128 string: little endian
} BLE_UUID128;

//
// STEP 0: Character declare
//
const BLE_CHAR AttCharList[] = {
  // =====  GATT ===== DO NOT CHANGE!
  {TYPE_CHAR, 0x0003, {ATT_CHAR_PROP_RD, 0x04, 0, 0x00, 0x2a}, UUID16_FORMAT}, //name
  //05-06 reserved

  // ===== Device Information Service Characteristics ===== DO NOT CHANGE!
  {TYPE_CHAR, 0x0008, {ATT_CHAR_PROP_RD, 0x09, 0, 0x29, 0x2a}, UUID16_FORMAT}, //manufacture
  {TYPE_CHAR, 0x000a, {ATT_CHAR_PROP_RD, 0x0b, 0, 0x26, 0x2a}, UUID16_FORMAT}, //firmware version
  {TYPE_CHAR, 0x000e, {ATT_CHAR_PROP_RD, 0x0f, 0, 0x28, 0x2a}, UUID16_FORMAT}, //sw version

  // ===== Item Service Characteristics =====
  {TYPE_CHAR, 0x11, {ATT_CHAR_PROP_RD | ATT_CHAR_PROP_W | ATT_CHAR_PROP_W_NORSP | ATT_CHAR_PROP_NTF | ATT_CHAR_PROP_IND, 0x12, 0, 0, 0 },1}, // Characteristic
  {TYPE_CFG,  0x13, {ATT_CHAR_PROP_RD|ATT_CHAR_PROP_W}},                                           // Client Characteristic Configuration
  {TYPE_INFO, 0x14},                                                                              // Characteristic User Description
  {TYPE_PRESENTATION_FORMAT, 0x15},   
};

// List of 128-bit UUIDs
const BLE_UUID128 AttUuid128List[] = {
  {0x8f, 0x2e, 0x78, 0x51, 0xba, 0xfb, 0x95, 0xb9, 0xca, 0x41, 0x28, 0x3f, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe2, 0xcc},
  {0x8f, 0x2e, 0x78, 0x51, 0xba, 0xfb, 0x95, 0xb9, 0xca, 0x41, 0x28, 0x3f, 0x01, 0x00, 0xe2, 0xcc},
};

uint8_t GetCharListDim(void)
{
  return sizeof(AttCharList) / sizeof(AttCharList[0]);
}


//
// STEP 1: Service declare
//
void att_server_rdByGrType( uint8_t pdu_type, uint8_t attOpcode, uint16_t st_hd, uint16_t end_hd, uint16_t att_type )
{
  // GAP and GATT (start handle 0x01)
  if ((att_type == GATT_PRIMARY_SERVICE_UUID) && (st_hd == 1)) //hard code for device info service
  {
    //GAP Device Name
    uint8_t t[] = {0x00, 0x18};
    att_server_rdByGrTypeRspPrimaryService(pdu_type, 0x1, 0x6, (uint8_t*)(t), 2);
    return;
  }
  // Device Info Service (start handle 0x07)
  else if ((att_type == GATT_PRIMARY_SERVICE_UUID) && (st_hd <= 0x07))
  {
    uint8_t t[] = {0xa, 0x18};
    att_server_rdByGrTypeRspPrimaryService(pdu_type, 0x7, 0xf, (uint8_t*)(t), 2);
    return;
  }
  // Item Service (start handle 0x20 (??) )
  else if ((att_type == GATT_PRIMARY_SERVICE_UUID) && (st_hd <= 0x10))
  {
    att_server_rdByGrTypeRspPrimaryService(pdu_type, 0x10, 0x19, (uint8_t*)(AttUuid128List[0].uuid128), 16);
    return;
  }

  ///error handle
  att_notFd( pdu_type, attOpcode, st_hd );
}


//
// STEP 2: data coming
// write response
void ser_write_rsp(uint8_t pdu_type/*reserved*/, uint8_t attOpcode/*reserved*/,
                   uint16_t att_hd, uint8_t* attValue/*app data pointer*/, uint8_t valueLen_w/*app data size*/)
{
  switch (att_hd)
  {
    case 0x12:
      // copy the first byte of written data into the item characteristic value
      memcpy(&itemCharacteristicValue, attValue, 1);
      bItemCharacteristicValueChanged = true;
      ser_write_rsp_pkt(pdu_type);  /*if the related character has the property of WRITE(with response) or TYPE_CFG, one MUST invoke this func*/
      break;
    case 0x13:
      // write to the Client Characteristic Configuration Descriptor
      memcpy(&cccd, attValue, 2);
      ser_write_rsp_pkt(pdu_type);
    default:
      att_notFd(pdu_type, attOpcode, att_hd );  /*the default response, also for the purpose of error robust */
      break;
  }
}


//
// STEP 3: Read data
// read response
void server_rd_rsp(uint8_t attOpcode, uint16_t attHandle, uint8_t pdu_type)
{
  uint8_t  d_len;
  uint8_t* ble_name = getDeviceInfoData(&d_len);

  switch (attHandle) // hard code
  {
    case 0x04: // GAP name
      att_server_rd( pdu_type, attOpcode, attHandle, ble_name, d_len);
      break;

    case 0x09: // MANU_INFO
      att_server_rd( pdu_type, attOpcode, attHandle, (uint8_t*)(MANU_INFO), sizeof(MANU_INFO) - 1);
      break;

    case 0x0b: // FIRMWARE_INFO
      att_server_rd(pdu_type, attOpcode, attHandle, GetFirmwareInfo(), strlen((const char*)GetFirmwareInfo()));
      break;

    case 0x0f:  // SOFTWARE_INFO
      att_server_rd(pdu_type, attOpcode, attHandle, (uint8_t*)(SOFTWARE_INFO), sizeof(SOFTWARE_INFO) - 1);
      break;

    case 0x12:  // Item Characteristic Value
      att_server_rd(pdu_type, attOpcode, attHandle, &itemCharacteristicValue, 1);
      break;

    case 0x13:  // Item Client Characteristic Configuration
      {
        att_server_rd(pdu_type, attOpcode, attHandle, cccd, 2);
      }
      break;

    case 0x14:  // Item Characteristic User Description
      att_server_rd(pdu_type, attOpcode, attHandle, (uint8_t*) itemCharacteristicUserDescription, sizeof(itemCharacteristicUserDescription));
      break;
      
    case 0x15: // Item Characteristic Presentation Format
      att_server_rd(pdu_type, attOpcode, attHandle, (uint8_t*)itemCharacteristicPresentationFormat, sizeof(itemCharacteristicPresentationFormat));
      break;

    default:
      att_notFd( pdu_type, attOpcode, attHandle );/*the default response, also for the purpose of error robust */
      break;
  }
}


void ser_prepare_write(unsigned short handle, unsigned char* attValue, unsigned short attValueLen, unsigned short att_offset) {

}


void ser_execute_write(void) {

}


void server_blob_rd_rsp(uint8_t attOpcode, uint16_t attHandle, uint8_t dataHdrP, uint16_t offset)
{
  
}

//return 1 means found
int GetPrimaryServiceHandle(unsigned short hd_start, unsigned short hd_end,
                            unsigned short uuid16,
                            unsigned short* hd_start_r, unsigned short* hd_end_r)
{
  return 0;
}


void gatt_user_send_notify_data_callback(void)
{

}


uint8_t* getsoftwareversion(void)
{
  return (uint8_t*)SOFTWARE_INFO;
}


static unsigned char gConnectedFlag = 0;

char GetConnectedStatus(void)
{
  return gConnectedFlag;
}


void ConnectStausUpdate(unsigned char IsConnectedFlag) //porting api
{
  LED_ONOFF(!IsConnectedFlag);

  if (IsConnectedFlag != gConnectedFlag)
  {
    gConnectedFlag = IsConnectedFlag;
  }
}


void UsrProcCallback(void) //porting api
{
  return;
}


unsigned char aes_encrypt_HW(unsigned char *_data, unsigned char *_key)
{
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you advertising the service? We are also using a custom UUID and iOS apps show all services after connecting and only the advertised services before

Comment: Are you sure your GATT database structure isn't broken?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. What is the way to advertise it correctly? And why does Android find it? What is the correct GATT database structure? Are there good tutorials on this for low level code?

Comment: I added the code to the original question.

Comment: I fixed the issue by using different handles. But now, the device is disconnected shortly after writing the value. Does someone have any idea?